# Linking quotation environment with citation styles

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

I was just wondering if it is possible to combine citation commands (preferably of `biblatex`) with quotation environments.

The reason is this:

In German language papers you often have two choices (besides some formal ones).

1. You either use a paraphrase/summary and add the source with the abbreviation "*Vgl.*" (engl. compare).
2. Or you use a direct quotation with quotation marks and a source without "*Vgl.*".

Linking them together would save the author some work because it would avoid the need for manual adjustments.

Two examples:

> This is a summary. (Vgl. Bauer 2009)
>
> "This is a quotation" (Bauer 2009)

My question is:
Is it possible to define the `\cite` command in a quotation sensitive way that

1. automatically generates a *Vgl.*-less output (for example "`(Bauer 2009)`") when used in a quotation environment? And that
2. generates a *Vgl.* output (for example "`(Vgl. Bauer 2009)`") when used without quotation mark?

Comment: Please be aware with phrases like: *In German language papers you usually have two choices*. The basic rules are defined in DIN 1505 Teil 3.

Comment: And, to add to @MarcoDaniel’s comment, there are numerous citation styles in Germany (and elsewhere), depending on the field you work in – and in some fields every journal or department has its own style guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that a) "quotation environment"  actually stands for text enclosed in quotation marks b) you are willing to use the [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package to handle quotation marks (note that its use is recommended for `biblatex`), you may do the following:

- Declare a new boolean switch `withintextquote` (which is initially set to false);
- Patch `biblatex`' `prenote` bibmacro so that it will add the (new) bibliography string `compare` plus a space if the `withintextquote` switch is set to false;
- Patch `csquotes`' internal `\csq@tquote@i` macro so that it will set the `withintextquote` switch locally to true.

EDIT: The automatic `compare` prenote is now overridden if the user adds an explicite prenote to the citation command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}% loaded by `biblatex` 

\newbool{withintextquote}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\csq@tquote@i}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\booltrue{withintextquote}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

\textcquote{A01}{This is a direct quotation}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose it works. But in my case it doesnt. The console (of TexShop 2.43) is telling me this:


<argument> \ExplFileName 
                         
l.30 ...e}{\ExplFileVersion}{\ExplFileDescription}

Comment: @Philip Your version of LaTeX3 packages may be too old for `xpatch`. I removed the `xpatch` dependency in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since quoted text is text, and a prenote is text, then quoted text can be the prenote (at the logical level).

At the practical level:

An experiment (using macros to store and enquote the text, for potential automation later):

```
\cite[\qmenquote{\qmuseq{q001}} \textemdash ][]{abook}
```

where `\qmenquote` is defined as

```
\newcommand\qmenquote[1]{\enquote{#1}}% from the csquotes package
```

and `\qmuseq` is defined as

```
\newcommand\qmuseq[1]{\csname qm:#1\endcsname}
```

with the CS `qm:q001` being defined as

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname qm:q001\endcsname{The cat sat on the mat.}
```

gives

[image: prenote quote]

for a given `abook` entry in the bib file and `english` option for `csquotes`.

A potential use for this could be where the prenote is a variable, and the \cite is "expanded" in one version to include the quote, and  in the other version to have the cf (or a paraphrase, or nothing).

This suggests the possibility of being automatic in the "vertical" dimension, rather than (or in addition to) the "horizontal" direction - that is, for example, via a loop, or a conditional. An application could be as transliterations, versus translations, versus original text.

Last item in the list in the Code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib} 
@book{abook,
author = {An Author},
title = {A Title）},
date = {2019-04-16},
location={A Location},
publisher={A Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\expandafter\newcommand\csname qm:q001\endcsname{The cat sat on the mat.}
\newcommand\mycf{\textit{Vgl.}}
\newcommand\qmuseq[1]{\csname qm:#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\qmenquote[1]{\enquote{#1}}
\newcommand\qmaddsep[1]{#1\ \textemdash\ }
\newcommand\qmcite[3]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax \cite[\mycf][#3]{#2}\else
\qmaddsep{\qmenquote{\qmuseq{#1}}}\cite[#3]{#2}\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item text: \qmuseq{q001}
\item enquoted: \qmenquote{\qmuseq{q001}}
\item with sep: \qmaddsep{\qmenquote{\qmuseq{q001}}}
\item quote with cite: \qmcite{q001}{abook}{S 123}
\item no quote with cite: \qmcite{}{abook}{S 123}
\item quote and no postnote: \qmcite{q001}{abook}{}
\item no quote and no postnote: \qmcite{}{abook}{}
\item \textbackslash textquote: \textquote[{\cite[S 456]{abook}}]{\qmuseq{q001}}
\item using the prenote \cite[\qmenquote{\qmuseq{q001}} \textemdash ][]{abook}
\end{enumerate}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Besides `\enquote`, `csquotes` package also has the handy `\textquote` command.